# Class design: Access a List<T> directly or through methods?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

For a newsroom system I have a class that contains a single news story. Inside this class is a private variable holding a generic List of image classes. The idea being a single story can contain multiple images.

The question is should I make the List variable public, so that I can add/remove images by addressing the List directly

```
public class News
{
    private _images List<Images>();

    public Images
    {
      get { return _images; }
      set { _images = value }
    }
}
```

or

Should I make the List variable private and then create methods to manipulate it:

```
public class News
{
    private _images List<Images>();

    public void AddImage( Image image )
    public Image GetImage( int imageId )
    public int GetImageCount()
    public void DeleteImage( int imageId )
}
```

My spider sense is telling me to do the later, as it's abstracting things more. But on the flip side its creating more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would explose a read-only view of the list as IList or IEnumerable, and methods for adding and removing elements. Like this:

```
public class News
{
    private _images List<Images>();

    public IList<Image> Images
    {
        get {return _images.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AddImage(Image image)
    {
        _images.Add(image);
        // Do other stuff...
    }

    public void DeleteImage(Image image)
    {
        _images.Remove(image);
        // Do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the Images property is missing the 'get {' part here?

Comment: Using IList exposes the implementation (i.e. the knowledge that it is a List) - sometimes this is being overly specific and it is worth using a more general type such as ICollection.

Comment: @Matt: Notice I did say at the top "as IList or IEnumerable". Surely IEnumerable<T> is general enough.

Answer (score 8):

By exposing the List, you expose an implementation detail. It will make it easier in the short run, but you'll have a hard time later if you decide to e.g. change the list to some other container (perhaps you need a Dictionary for lookup or something).

I would encapsulate it as it will make the type easier to maintain and enhance in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you expose the list as a property then it will be possible to do the following from outside the class:

```
News.Images = new List<Images>();
```

Is that what you want? (and you shouldn't because it breaks allsorts of encapsulation principles)

If not then use an ICollection<T> interface:

```
class News
{
    public ICollection<Image> Images   
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
 }
```

or

```
class News
{
    private List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    public ICollection<Image> Images   
    {
        get
        {
             // You can return an ICollection interface directly from a List
             return images;
        }
    }
 }
```

ICollection<T> has methods such as Add, Remove, Clear, Count.

If you want a read-only container return a ReadOnlyCollection

```
class News
{
    private List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Image> Images   
    {
        get
        {
             // This wraps the list in a ReadOnlyCollection object so it doesn't actually copy the contents of the list just a reference to it
             return images.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you need/(would need) to control adding/getting and deleting images or possibility to change container.

Answer (score 1):

Davy Brion made a post on this last week. He favors exposing an IEnumerable<> property and providing an add & remove method for manipulation.

Most of the time you only want to loop through the collection, so IEnumerable<> will do the trick. Besides, you can switch the actual implementation (List, Set, ...) when needed without any hassle, when switching to another ORM this could prove very valuable.

http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/10/stop-exposing-collections-already/

Comment: By exposing an ICollection you can change the underlying implementation - the only argument to not use ICollection is if you need to be notified if the contents of the collection change.

Comment: ICollection is indeed a valid alternative, it all depends on what you'll want to do with the "collection". If you're just going to loop through it: IEnumerable, if you want to know the size at some point: ICollection. It's a matter of taste at this level, as long as you don't use IList it's ok I guess.

Comment: Agreed - it is a case of knowing the benefits & disadvantages of each method. I seem to remember somewhere that using the Linq .Count will just return the .Count of a list rather than looping through all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Expose a read only implementation of the list and expose methods for manipulating the list. I would do it like this:

```
public class News
{
    private IList<Image> _images;

    public void News()
    {
        _images = new List<Image>();
    }

    public void AddImage(Image image) { ... }
    public void RemoveImage(Image image) { ... }

    public IEnumberable<Image> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
    }
}
```

Note that the Images property can be cast as List but you can return it in a ReadyOnlyCollection wrapper if needed. Count() and ElementAt() extension methods replace your GetImageCount and GetImage methods.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the elements you could consider using a ReadOnlyCollection or IEnumerable type. However in order to keep encapsulation ensured, you should use insert/remove methods, this way you don't need the set of the property anymore.

Edit: Someone beat me to it during typing this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a design consideration that only you can decide. Your second approach is hiding an implementation detail that is you used a `List` to store images. On the other side, the first solution gives you one advantage. You can use all the `List` methods including those extensions that are always useful. Using the second solution, you can also implement a `ToList()` method that would return a new constructed `List`. Changes to this `List` wouldn't affect the internal structure of your `class`. The down side is, if the internal Image `List` is too big, it could affect performance, as it would always build a new `List` on `ToList()` but I wouldn't expect this method be called many times.

Another solution would be to expose a `ReadOnlyCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the List directly, you would have to rely on it's mechanics for all Image-related actions (Add, Delete, Count, ...)

I would still expose a collection of Images (ReadOnlyCollection is usually fine) to make the accessing operations of the list easier for both the developer and the consumer, but all create/update/delete logic should be wrapped inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

I would just expose the list as an IList:

```
public class News
{
    private List<Image> _images;

    public IList<Image> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; }
    }
}
```

If you later want to change the implementation, you can do this without breaking the contract:

```
public class News
{
    public News(SomeCollection<Image> images)
    {
        _images = images;
        Images = new ListView(this);
    }

    private SomeCollection<Image> _images;

    public IList<Image> Images { get; private set; }

    private class News.ListView : IList<Image>
    {
        public ListView(News news)
        {
            _news = news;
        }

        private News _news;

        // Implement the methods to manipulate _news._images
    }
}
```